# accessing state inside class in react

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I have the following code for a react component.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import CalcButton from './CalcButton';
import Operand from './Operand';
import '../custom.css';

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      prevVal: '',
      currentVal: ''
    }
  }

  handleOpClick(event) {
    console.log('------------event------', event.target.value);
    console.log(this.state.currentVal);
    this.setState({
      currentVal: 'test'
    })
  }

  render() {

    const firstRow = ["7", "8", "9"];
    const secRow = ["4", "5", "6"];
    const thirdRow = ["1", "2", "3",];
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="app">
          <div className="inpCont">
            <input
            type="text"
            className="inpBox"
            value={this.state.currentVal}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="btnCont">
            <div className="btnRow">
            {
              firstRow.map((row, index) => {
                return <CalcButton
                  handleClick={(event) => {
                    this.setState({
                      currentVal: this.state.currentVal + event.target.value
                    });
                  }}
                  key={index}
                  number={row} />;
              })
            }
            <Operand
              handleOpClick={this.handleOpClick}
              operator="/" />
            </div>
            <div className="btnRow">
            {
              secRow.map((row, index) => {
                return <CalcButton
                  handleClick={(event) => {
                    this.setState({
                      currentVal: this.state.currentVal + event.target.value
                    });
                  }}
                  key={index}
                  number={row}/>;
              })
            }
            <Operand
              handleOpClick={this.handleOpClick}
              operator="*" />
            </div>
            <div className="btnRow">
            {
              thirdRow.map((row, index) => {
                return <CalcButton
                  handleClick={(event) => {
                    this.setState({
                      currentVal: this.state.currentVal + event.target.value
                    });
                  }}
                  key={index}
                  number={row} />;
              })
            }
            <Operand
              handleOpClick={this.handleOpClick}
              operator="+" />
            </div>
            <div className="btnRow">
            <Operand
              handleOpClick={this.handleOpClick}
              operator="Clear" />
            <Operand
              handleOpClick={this.handleOpClick}
              operator="=" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

When I try to access the state inside the handleOpClick method of the class, it throws the following error.

```
App.jsx:18 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of null
    at handleOpClick (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:32849:24)
    at Object.ReactErrorUtils.invokeGuardedCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:17144:17)
    at executeDispatch (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:16927:22)
    at Object.executeDispatchesInOrder (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:16950:6)
    at executeDispatchesAndRelease (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:16338:23)
    at executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:16349:11)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at forEachAccumulated (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:17247:10)
    at Object.processEventQueue (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:16552:8)
    at runEventQueueInBatch (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:24174:19)
```

How do I access state inside component class method. I want to write common logic to handle operator click. Where am I going wrong ?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use `ES5`, you can use `handleOpClick={this.handleOpClick}` as above. But in `ES6`, you should bind the context to the current class and you can do this using one of the below three ways.

1. You can change all your `handleOpClick={this.handleOpClick}` to `handleOpClick={this.handleOpClick.bind(this)}`
2. Or, change all `handleOpClick={this.handleOpClick}` to arrow function as `handleOpClick={evt => this.handleOpClick(evt)}`
3. Or, Keep all `handleOpClick={this.handleOpClick}` but change the original method `handleOpClick` to arrow function as mentioned by Panther.

Like,

```
 handleOpClick = (event) => {
    console.log('------------event------', event.target.value);
    console.log(this.state.currentVal);
    this.setState({
      currentVal: 'test'
    })
  }
```

Comment: Note that options 1 and 3 are somewhat more favorable as they don’t need the creation of a function on each render pass, so I would favor those if you can get away with it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind `handleOpClick` to the components instance context(this). You can use ES6 arrow functions to achieve this.

```
 handleOpClick = (event) => {
    console.log('------------event------', event.target.value);
    console.log(this.state.currentVal);
    this.setState({
      currentVal: 'test'
    })
  }
```